# Write a DataFrame on a Google Sheet using Google Sheet API v4 and batchUpdate in Python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api

I am trying to write the content of a dataframe on Google Sheets using Google Sheets API v4 and the batchUpdate method.

To do so, I transform the dataframe to a list of lists, each list representing one row, but I get the following error:

`TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable`

My dataFrame contains int64 and strings types.

```
#Transforming my dataframe to a list of lists
values = []
#Title line
values.append(list(orders_compact.columns))
#Adding each row
for i in range (0,len(orders_compact)):
    values.append(list(orders_compact.iloc[i]))

batch_update_values_request_body = {

    # How the input data should be interpreted.
    'value_input_option': 'USER_ENTERED',  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

    # The new values to apply to the spreadsheet.
    'data': values,  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

    # TODO: Add desired entries to the request body.
}

request = service.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, body=batch_update_values_request_body)
response = request.execute()
```

I have tried to change the type using astype or to "jsonify" the dataframe using the .to_json method, to bypass the issue both without success.

This should write the entire content of the DataFrame in the spreadsheet defined in SPREADSHEET_ID (the credentials part being tested and validated).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You have to convert all int64 into string. Use str() method or astype() method